# I made a pretty cool formula does it exist anywhere else?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

So I’ve made a formula that takes 2 angles and a base and depending on which angle you put in first gives you one of the 2 other sides and by using certain parts of the formula and it’s inverses you can solve pretty much any triangle problem (I think) I’d like to see if this formula already exists with that being said here’s the formula

[image: arcbase formula I like to call it]

edit#1: Hey I’m seeing a lot of downvotes on this post I’m a little confused on why please explain in the comments! That would be supper great of you thanks and have a good day!

edit#2: here is the work I did to get this formula it’s a little messy but overall it gives a good idea on how I made it https://docs.google.com/file/d/10w19VOlA_dAIrL6ZFsB6pq7sd1JdffhB/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msword

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Shaun this will be very helpful I'm a little new so sorry about that.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Be nice!

Comment: @JairTaylor It’s okay though yeah if you do downvote do explain why I’m a little confused myself on what I did wrong lol.

Comment: @SelfProclaimedDev Perhaps it would help if you gave a derivation of your formula or at least a sketch of a derivation.

Comment: The formula should be updated to handle the case when $\theta_1 = 90$. The only tangent in the formula would be undefined.

Comment: @SelfProclaimedDev: Welcome to MathSE, and congratulations on your discovery! That excitement you sense at having derived a result is the kind of thing that makes math rewarding! ... That said, your result simplifies a bit; when the dust settles, you find the [Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), which, as it happens, is quite well-known. ... Don't let it get you down. The fact that someone got to a result before you is, as the late, great Steve Fisk would say, "an accident of Time"; it does not diminish your personal accomplishment. ... Stay curious!

Comment: @peterwhy the reason why that is, is because a 90 degree angle is a straight line up which is impossible given the real plane of the graph though it would be interesting to see what happens in the complex plane might be something you could see for yourself however when the angle is 90 I recommend not using the second half of the formula with cotangent and just keep the base variable in hope this helps!

Comment: @Blue That would be a good answer.

Comment: @Blue Sorry if I’m mistaken but would it also possible to derive the law of cosines by converting some parts of the equation into there inverses. I ask this because I’ve used the formula as a substitute for law of cosines when testing it but I do understand where you are coming from I think it’s just interesting how well trigonometry is all connected!

Comment: @JairTaylor I don’t understand what you mean could you elaborate on what you mean when you say derivation? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @SelfProclaimedDev By "derivation" I just mean you should give an idea of how you arrived at this formula.

Comment: @SelfProclaimedDev Since the goal is to solve triangles, having $\theta_1 = 90$ and $0<\theta_2 < 90$ for the two base angles is quite a normal use case, in my opinion. The formula also misses the case when $\theta_1 > 90$ and $\theta_1+\theta_2 < 180$, when the root is positive and the cotangent fraction is negative.\

Comment: @JairTaylor Well lucky me I documented most of my work lemme find it rq.

Comment: @peterwhy yes I am aware of those 2 problems but I was not able to find a way to fix them but hopefully you or someone else can!

Comment: @SelfProclaimedDev Some identities for you:

$$\begin{align*}
\tan\left(\theta + 3\pi\right) &= \tan\theta\\
\tan^2\theta + 1 &= \sec^2 \theta\\
\sec\theta \cot\theta &= \csc\theta
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @peterwhy Oh thank you very much I’m self taught so I’ve never heard of these simplifications before they look very interesting I’ll take a look at them thanks again!

Comment: As an aside, seeing all of these $\frac{\pi}{180}$'s thrown around... you should consider thinking in terms of radians instead of degrees to begin with, or better yet to just let your variables $\theta$ be in the representation that your circle functions accept as arguments.  There is no reason to take so much time to write and to harm the readability of your work by including these $\frac{\pi}{180}$'s so many places.

Comment: @JMoravitz good tip I was just trying to specify that the angles need to be converted though I’ll take that into account when working on my next formula.

Comment: As for the identities mentioned by peterwhy, they should be selfexplanatory but one way that you can arrive at them is to rewrite everything just in terms of sines and cosines.  $\tan^2(\theta)+1=\sec^2(\theta)$ for instance is just another way of writing $\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)}+1=\frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta)}$ which by multiplying both sides by $\cos^2(\theta)$ you are back to the familiar $\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$ which you should know from definitions.

Comment: That makes sense thank you for the information!

Comment: Heartening to see a +6 reaction to the -5

Comment: @FShrike Indeed it is I do hope I can really flourish in my learning with this community can’t wait for what comes next!

Comment: That's good to hear. To be clear, people downvoted your question because they thought it wasn't exactly a clear question but rather a demonstration of something that you'd already figured out, making it (in their eyes) not especially appropriate. In your future questions you should try to avoid this

Comment: @FShrike will try to though I do love to show my formulas to others to see what they can do with them and what feedback I can gain from it!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let's simplify your formula:

$$h=\left(\sqrt{\left(\tan\left(\theta_1\frac{\pi}{180}+3\pi\right)\right)^2+1}\right)\left(\left(\frac{\cot\left(\theta_1\frac{\pi}{180}\right)}{\left(\cot\left(\theta_1\frac{\pi}{180}\right)+\cot\left(\theta_2\frac{\pi}{180}\right)\right)}\right)b\right)$$

First, let's agree that either all angles are in degrees and the trigonometric functions are calculated with the argument in degrees, or all angles are in radians and the trigonometric functions are calculated with the argument in radians: avoid mixing. The resulting formula doesn't need the factor $\frac{\pi}{180}$ anymore:

$$h=\left(\sqrt{\left(\tan(\theta_1+3\pi)\right)^2+1}\right)\left(\left(\frac{\cot\theta_1}{\left(\cot\theta_1+\cot\theta_2\right)}\right)b\right)$$

Next thing: $\tan(x+3\pi)=\tan x$ so we don't need $3\pi$ (also dispose of some unnecessary pairs of parentheses):

$$h=\left(\sqrt{\tan^2\theta_1+1}\right)\left(\frac{\cot\theta_1}{\cot\theta_1+\cot\theta_2}\right)b$$

Now, $\tan^2 x+1=\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}+1=\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}+\frac{\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}$, so $\sqrt{\tan^2x+1}=\frac{1}{|\cos x|}$. This lets us transform this further:

$$h=\frac{1}{|\cos\theta_1|}\left(\frac{\cot\theta_1}{\cot\theta_1+\cot\theta_2}\right)b$$

The next thing we should do is write all the $\cot$'s as $\frac{\cos}{\sin}$:

$$h=\frac{1}{|\cos\theta_1|}\left(\frac{\frac{\cos\theta_1}{\sin\theta_1}}{\frac{\cos\theta_1}{\sin\theta_1}+\frac{\cos\theta_2}{\sin\theta_2}}\right)b$$

which is the same as:

$$h=\frac{1}{|\cos\theta_1|}\left(\frac{\cos\theta_1\sin\theta_2}{\cos\theta_1\sin\theta_2+\cos\theta_2\sin\theta_1}\right)b$$

or:

$$h=\frac{\cos\theta_1}{|\cos\theta_1|}\left(\frac{\sin\theta_2}{\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)}\right)b$$

or:

$$h=\text{sgn}(\cos\theta_1)\times b\frac{\sin\theta_2}{\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)}$$

where $\text{sgn}\,x=\begin{cases}1&x>0\\0&x=0\\-1&x<0\end{cases}$, and $\text{sgn}(\cos\theta_1)$ is in fact what you get when you cancel $\cos\theta_1$ with $|\cos\theta_1|$ in the previous line.

The last step is: if the *third* angle in the triangle is $\theta_3$, then $\theta_3=\pi-(\theta_1+\theta_2)$ and $\sin\theta_3=\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)$, so **your formula** gives us:

$$h=\text{sgn}(\cos\theta_1)\times b \frac{\sin\theta_2}{\sin\theta_3}$$

Now, knowing the [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), we can see that this is true up to the sign: the Law of sines states that:

$$\frac{h}{\sin\theta_2}=\frac{b}{\sin\theta_3}$$

i.e.

$$h=b \frac{\sin\theta_2}{\sin\theta_3}$$

which means that your formula is *almost* correct. The only problem with it is (apart from not working at all for $\theta_1=\pi/2$) that, for $\pi/2<\theta_1<\pi$ (where $\cos\theta_1$ is negative) it gives the result with the opposite sign of what it should be. Otherwise, it is a correct, albeit long-winded, expression equivalent to the Law of sines.

Comment: Ty sm that simplification really helps with understanding the flaws within the formula Now I wonder if I can find a way to fix them.

Comment: Well, a quick'n'dirty fix would be to slap the modulus around the whole formula (thus making it always positive, as it should be, as $h$ is always positive). This won't solve the problem of a right angle $\theta_1$ or $\theta_2$ but will solve the case $\pi/2<\theta_1<\pi$. This won't help making the formula any simpler, though. The Law of sines is probably the simplest version of the correct formula. It is also incredibly easy to prove using the areas of the triangle.

Comment: for right triangles you can remove the cotangent part of the formula and it should work fine.

Comment: (Sorry, meant to say for right angle $\theta_1$: $\theta_2=\pi/2$ is not a problem for the formula.)

Comment: All good thanks again for all your help I do hope I can learn more from people like you in this community as It’s been hard to find people interested in this stuff lately.